# const ref binding to internal resource of rvalue

Tags: c++, c++11, temporary, const-reference

Consider the code:

`const Resource& r = ResourceContainer("foo").myResource;`

What does the standard say about the lifetime of myResource?

Similar, but not sure if this is equivalent: now imagine that it was being implicitly converted via `operator const Resource&()`. Does that make a difference?

`const Resource& r = ResourceContainer("foo");`

Comment: Note: if this question has been asked before, send me the link and I will gladly delete this duplicate question. Otherwise if it's really the first time such was asked, after so many years, then Wow! doesn't deserve a down vote IMO

Answer (score 1):

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary says:

> Whenever a reference is bound to a temporary or to a subobject thereof, the lifetime of the temporary is extended to match the lifetime of the reference, with the following exceptions:

"Subobject thereof" looks like your case.

Comment: Thanks bipll. I once a situation where this crashed on gcc, though not on MSVC. Although there was an added wrinkle in that it was being implicitly converted via `operator Resource&()`. Does that make a difference?

Comment: it is interesting to see that they explicitly excluded user defined conversion in the section on static_cast  here: http://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#6